# Changing color of shapes using vba

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, vba

I have inserted a bunch of rectangle shapes within my spreadsheet.  They are called:

Rectangle 1
thru
Rectangle 172

Is there some code I could use to change the fill and line color?  I would assign the code to another button that would change it.

Comment: you want to change ALL at once, or one based upon it being selected? If so you could by-pass using a button and just change color when clicking on the rectangle you want

Answer (score 1):

see if this will adapt to your needs make each rectangle call this macro

```
Sub doRectChange()
 Dim c
  c = Application.Caller
 MsgBox (c)
  With ActiveSheet.Shapes(c)
   .Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 3
   .Fill.Transparency = 0#
   .Line.Weight = 3#
   .Line.DashStyle = msoLineSolid
   .Line.Style = msoLineSingle
   .Line.Transparency = 0#
   .Line.Visible = msoTrue
   .Line.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 6
  End With
 End Sub
```

**Here is an alternative**
Of course your button numbers may be different so adjust for that.

```
Sub allRectanglesColor()
Dim c
Dim color
c = Application.Caller
'MsgBox (c)
Select Case c
Case "Button 1"
color = 10
Case "Button 2"
color = 12
Case "Button 3"
color = 17
End Select
ActiveSheet.Rectangles.Select
 With Selection.ShapeRange
    .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
    .Fill.Solid
    .Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = color
 End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I have three buttons that are labled "Blue", "Green", & "Red".  When I click each button I would like for the color of all rectangles to change to that color.

Comment: It's not the buttons that change colors, it's the 172 rectangles after I click the buttons.  Thanks

Comment: The second code version I provided, will change the color of all rectangles based upon the button selected. The buttons in my sample assumed "red" is "Button 1", "blue" is "Button 2", "green" is "Button 3"

Comment: assign the same macro to each of the button

Comment: was this not what you were trying to achieve? It should be simple to accomplish what you wanted @Mike